# FileNotFoundError trying to get mp3 file

Tags: python, django, pydub

I'm trying to use [pydub](http://pydub.com/) to convert uploaded mp3s to a certain bitrate, using this code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

def process_mp3(mp3, id):
    print(mp3) # media/track1-original
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3)
    bitrates = [128, 192, 256, 320]

    for bitrate in bitrates:
        audio.export(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + 'track' + id + '-' + bitrate, format="mp3", bitrate=bitrate + 'k')

def save_file(file, name):

    with open(default_storage.path(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + name), 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    return name
```

I'm getting this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Systemet finner ikke angitt fil

And the code that calls `process_mp3` is (Note: track_obj is a Django model object and the ID is from a database):

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

....

mp3 = save_file(mp3, 'track' + str(track_obj.id) + '-' + 'original')

mp3_info = MP3('media/' + mp3); # This works

process_mp3('media/' + mp3, str(track_obj.id)) # This does not
```

Apparently, mutagen can read the file just fine, but pydub cannot. What gives?

Comment: Try using the absolute path to the file instead of a relative path `media/...`

Comment: @Alasdair That's actually what I tried first and that caused both mutagen and pydub to throw that error.

Comment: did you try without the media directory? just try to keep the file in the current  directory and see if pydub sees the file to isolate the issue.

Comment: @Deva Yes, same error. It's important to note that I am using django, and the media directory is actually in the root folder of my project.

Comment: Have you made sure that the mp3 file was inside the same file as the code file?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played much with `mutagen` and hence was not able to get `track_obj.id` to work. Is it a `mutagen` attribute?

Also, since `track_obj.id` was not working, It was substituted with `track` using `audio["TIT2"].text[0]` by calling `mutagen.id3`

I removed all explicit references to `external paths` as well and simplified the paths and the code for testing purpose.

I also noticed that you were trying to `concatenate` `string` (`path, names` etc) with `int` ( `bitrate` ). That needed some fixing.

This code does not use `save_file` `function` so I can't comment on that.

Anyway, after all this, below code works and is able to save  `mp3` files with different `bitrate` by feeding it through `pydub`.

Here is working code , Hope this helps

**Working Code:**

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
from pydub import AudioSegment



def process_mp3(mp3, id):
    print(mp3) # media/track1-original
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3)
    bitrates = [128, 192, 256, 320]

    for bitrate in bitrates:
        export_file = my_media_path  + '/' + 'track_' + id + '-' + str(bitrate) +'.mp3'
        print ("exporting %s" % export_file)
        audio.export(export_file, format="mp3", bitrate= str(bitrate) + 'k')

def save_file(file, name):

    with open(default_storage.path(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + name), 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)


mp3 = "test.mp3"

mp3_info = MP3('media/' + mp3); # This works

my_media_path = 'media'
audio = ID3('media/' + 'test.mp3')
#print "audio_info = ",audio
track = audio["TIT2"].text[0]
process_mp3('media/' + mp3, str(track))
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
media/test.mp3
exporting media/track_End Matter-128.mp3
exporting media/track_End Matter-192.mp3
exporting media/track_End Matter-256.mp3
exporting media/track_End Matter-320.mp3
>>>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that this is from a django project, `track_obj` is a django model instance/object and the id is from that instance's database id. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah it still does not work, I don't understand why though cause I am passing the exact same thing to `process_mp3` that I am passing to mutagen's MP3 function, mutagen works, pydub does not.

Comment: You may not be passing same thing to `process_mp3`, `str(track_obj.id) is an extra parameter thats passed to that function. Have you tried to check if you get proper value for `"str(track_obj.id)"`before feeding it to `process_mp3` ?  Probably do some print statements to see what's being passed and executed.

Comment: The second parameter is just to insert the object id into the exported file name, ie "track1-128.mp3", it has nothing to do with actually getting the file, and besides the error happens on `audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3)`

Comment: Can you try with just `audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("<only_mp3_file_no_path>")` , like I did? I had mp3 file in root folder hence did not give any `absolute` or `relative` path. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows (Cannot download vm because of internet limitations) and doing that just threw this error: The program cannot start because "libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll" is missing on the computer.

Comment: Windows need "//" instead of single "/". So path for `media` will be `media//". Its trivial, but just wanted to make sure you are aware of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109192/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-anil-m).

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem, but pydub also accepts file handles (rather than paths):

try this?

```
with open("media/test.mp3", "rb") as f:
    AudioSegment.from_mp3(f)
```

Comment: Tried it, same excact error, this just refuses to work no matter what it seems. Everything else file related in my script works fine, but pydub just can't.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen are you getting a warning that pydub can't find ffmpeg/avlib? It could be the file that is missing is the ffmpeg executable (which is used to decode the mp3)

Comment: I installed ffmpeg though, but it did give me an error once saying it couldn't find fmmpeg, but that wasn't even when I was trying to have it read the file

Comment: @SebastianOlsen try setting the location of the ffmpeg binary with `AudioSegment.converter = "/path/to/ffmpeg"` ?

Comment: I should mention that I am using a virtualenv, could that maybe be the source of the problem? I have ffmpeg in the PATH env variable.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen I don't think that would affect anything - ffmpeg is just a binary file, e.g., `ffmpeg.exe` (on windows at least)